# PANIC: "Oops: 0000 [#1]" (check log for details) - Updated Kernel Tested

Tags: oop, crash, linux-kernel, kernel, panic

I'm trying to interpret a system crash that is repeatable, but but not that often.  I believe it has do with a third party driver and a optical scanning device.  I'm not sure if the driver for scanning device is causing the hang if it's bringing something out in a USB driver that causes the hang or if it's something totally different.

I'm not a driver developer, so I'm fumbling my way through the crash dump while reading the Linux Kernel Crash Book located here - http://rogunix.com/docs/Reversing&Exploiting/Linux_Kernel_Crash_Book.pdf .

I was able to setup a debug kernel with the kexec tools to produce a vmcore. With crash  is see the PANIC: "Oops: 0000 [#1]" (check log for details) and in the logs is see the BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00100100.

Can you help me interpret more of the dump so I can go back to the developer of the driver and tell them the findings or can you tell me is not the driver at all.

Here's more from the dump.  Many thanks in advance.

```
KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.18-194.el5debug/vmlinux
DUMPFILE: /root/kernel/vmcore_12032014
CPUS: 4
DATE: Sat Oct 20 16:51:55 2001
UPTIME: 00:03:55
LOAD AVERAGE: 0.79, 0.83, 0.38
TASKS: 128
NODENAME: 3232A
RELEASE: 2.6.18-194.el5debug
VERSION: #1 SMP Fri Apr 2 16:56:41 EDT 2010
MACHINE: i686  (1800 Mhz)
MEMORY: 2 GB
PANIC: "Oops: 0000 [#1]" (check log for details)
PID: 0
COMMAND: "swapper"
TASK: c069d460  (1 of 4)  [THREAD_INFO: c075f000]
CPU: 0
STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)
```

crash> bt

```
PID: 0      TASK: c069d460  CPU: 0   COMMAND: "swapper"
#0 [c080cdb0] crash_kexec at c044a386
#1 [c080cdf4] die at c04065c3
#2 [c080ce24] do_page_fault at c062d1b7
#3 [c080ce5c] error_code (via page_fault) at c0405bc3
    EAX: f7c7de2c  EBX: 000ffaec  ECX: 00000000  EDX: f4282e8c  EBP: f7c665a0
    DS:  007b      ESI: f7c7ddf8  ES:  007b      EDI: c080cea4
    CS:  0060      EIP: c05a2ef2  ERR: ffffffff  EFLAGS: 00010012
#4 [c080ce90] hiddev_send_event at c05a2ef2
#5 [c080cea0] hiddev_report_event at c05a2fcc
#6 [c080cec8] hid_input_report at c05a0fc3
#7 [c080cf1c] hid_irq_in at c05a261d
#8 [c080cf2c] usb_hcd_giveback_urb at c05964b6
#9 [c080cf3c] uhci_giveback_urb at f883f618 [uhci_hcd]
#10 [c080cf58] uhci_scan_schedule at f883fc14 [uhci_hcd]
#11 [c080cfa4] uhci_irq at f884163d [uhci_hcd]
#12 [c080cfc4] usb_hcd_irq at c0596f9b
#13 [c080cfcc] handle_IRQ_event at c0454d5f
#14 [c080cfe4] __do_IRQ at c0454e2d
--- <hard IRQ> ---
#0 [c075ff80] do_IRQ at c040761f
#1 [c075ff98] common_interrupt at c0405a28
    EAX: 00000000  EBX: c075f008  ECX: 00000000  EDX: 00000000  EBP: 00000020
    DS:  007b      ESI: c06440f8  ES:  007b      EDI: ca138790
    CS:  0060      EIP: c0403d0a  ERR: ffffff4e  EFLAGS: 00000246
#2 [c075ffcc] mwait_idle at c0403d0a
#3 [c075ffd4] cpu_idle at c0403cc4
```

crash> log

```
Scan:    First buffer received = 0x6
Scan:    Last packet of command transfer = 6  Command size 6
Scan:    0x2 0x51 0x88 0x80 0x81 0x3
Scan: Read data present
Scan: IOCTL_PS3_PEAK_MSG
Scan: In scanner_read    Scan: Copied 1 chunks of data to user space
usb 4-1: new full speed USB device using uhci_hcd and address 3
usb 4-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
pl2303 4-1:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
usb 4-1: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 00100100
 printing eip:
c05a2ef2
*pde = 76330067
Oops: 0000 [#1]
SMP
last sysfs file: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.2/usb4/4-1/bConfigurationValue
Modules linked in: vfat fat scan_drv_scanner(U) xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_state ip_conntrack nfnetlink iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables loop dm_mirror dm_multipath scsi_dh video backlight sbs power_meter hwmon i2c_ec dell_wmi wmi button battery asus_acpi ac lp joydev snd_hda_intel snd_seq_dummy sg snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss snd_pcm snd_timer snd_page_alloc parport_pc serio_raw snd_hwdep parport pl2303 snd soundcore i2c_i801 usbserial r8169 i2c_core mii pcspkr dm_raid45 dm_message dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod dm_mem_cache usb_storage ata_piix libata sd_mod scsi_mod ext3 jbd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_hcd
CPU:    0
EIP:    0060:[<c05a2ef2>]    Tainted: G      VLI
EFLAGS: 00010012   (2.6.18-194.el5debug #1)
EIP is at hiddev_send_event+0x65/0x95
eax: f7c7de2c   ebx: 000ffaec   ecx: 00000000   edx: f4282e8c
esi: f7c7ddf8   edi: c080cea4   ebp: f7c665a0   esp: c080ce94
ds: 007b   es: 007b   ss: 0068
Process swapper (pid: 0, ti=c080c000 task=c069d460 task.ti=c075f000)
Stack: f7cbba78 ca3ec000 c080cebc c05a2fd1 00000001 00000001 ffffffff 00000000
   00000000 00000000 00000005 f7cc857c c075ff9c c05a0fc8 f7c57348 00000002
   00000002 00000046 c06cbfb0 00000001 ca3ec000 f7cca001 f7cbba78 00000046
Call Trace:
 [<c05a2fd1>] hiddev_report_event+0x4b/0x52
 [<c05a0fc8>] hid_input_report+0x99/0x399
 [<c05a2622>] hid_irq_in+0x49/0xcc
 [<c05964b9>] usb_hcd_giveback_urb+0x28/0x53
 [<f883f61d>] uhci_giveback_urb+0x104/0x12b [uhci_hcd]
 [<f883fc19>] uhci_scan_schedule+0x4f0/0x76b [uhci_hcd]
 [<f8841642>] uhci_irq+0x118/0x12e [uhci_hcd]
 [<c0596f9e>] usb_hcd_irq+0x23/0x50
 [<c0454d61>] handle_IRQ_event+0x3e/0x8a
 [<c0454e32>] __do_IRQ+0x85/0xda
 [<c0454dad>] __do_IRQ+0x0/0xda
 [<c040761f>] do_IRQ+0xa4/0xd1
 [<c0405a2d>] common_interrupt+0x25/0x2c
 [<c0403d0a>] mwait_idle+0x2a/0x3d
 [<c0403cc6>] cpu_idle+0xa4/0xbe
 [<c0764a22>] start_kernel+0x39e/0x3a6
 =======================
Code: b9 01 00 02 00 ba 1d 00 00 00 40 83 e0 3f 89 83 00 06 00 00 8d 83 0c 06 00 00 e8 93 ac ee ff 8b 9b 14 06 00 00 81 eb 14 06 00 00 <8b> 83 14 06 00 00 0f 18 00 90 8d 93 14 06 00 00 8d 46 34 39 c2
EIP: [<c05a2ef2>] hiddev_send_event+0x65/0x95 SS:ESP 0068:c080ce94
```

**Updated Kernel Tested**

I have since updated to the latest CentOS 5.5 released kernel (2.6.18-371.6.1), but still got a kernel panic.  However this time the panic occured on the command "khubd" and not on "swapper".  I was able to capture the dump and below I have provided what I hope is relevant information to pinpoint this problem.  Is it a bug in the kernel or something in the driver?

```
KERNEL: /usr/lib/debug/lib/modules/2.6.18-371.6.1.el5debug/vmlinux
    DUMPFILE: /root/kernel2/HWID-2277-31032014/vmcore
        CPUS: 4
        DATE: Mon Mar 31 12:50:25 2014
      UPTIME: 2 days, 19:29:28
LOAD AVERAGE: 0.07, 0.09, 0.02
       TASKS: 181
    NODENAME: 32277
     RELEASE: 2.6.18-371.6.1.el5debug
     VERSION: #1 SMP Wed Mar 12 22:29:36 EDT 2014
     MACHINE: i686  (1800 Mhz)
      MEMORY: 2 GB
       PANIC: "Oops: 0000 [#1]" (check log for details)
         PID: 126
     COMMAND: "khubd"
        TASK: ca2fc5b0  [THREAD_INFO: f7fb2000]
         CPU: 3
       STATE: TASK_RUNNING (PANIC)
```

crash> bt

```
PID: 126    TASK: ca2fc5b0  CPU: 3   COMMAND: "khubd"
 #0 [f7fb2dfc] crash_kexec at c044da51
 #1 [f7fb2e40] die at c0406649
 #2 [f7fb2e70] do_page_fault at c0639449
 #3 [f7fb2eb0] device_del at c057053e
 #4 [f7fb2efc] device_del at c0570552
 #5 [f7fb2f10] device_unregister at c0570669
 #6 [f7fb2f18] usb_remove_ep_files at c05a3dac
 #7 [f7fb2f38] usb_remove_sysfs_dev_files at c05a39d6
 #8 [f7fb2f44] usb_disconnect at c059db59
 #9 [f7fb2f58] hub_thread at c059e663
#10 [f7fb2fcc] kthread at c0439ef6
#11 [f7fb2fe4] kernel_thread_helper at c0405e0d
```

crash> log (truncated)

```
Scan: no error - In command_callback
Scan: In command_callback
Scan:    First buffer received = 0x2a
Scan:    Last packet of command transfer = 42  Command size 42
Scan:    0x2 0x44 0x20 0x54 0x65 0x73 0x74 0x20 0x4d 0x65 0x73 0x73
Scan: Read data present
Scan: IOCTL_PS3_PEAK_MSG
Scan: In scanner_read    Scan: Copied 1 chunks of data to user space
Scan: IOCTL_PS3_SCANNER_COMMAND  Busy slots = 0x0        Total_slots = 0x8       Busy     image slots = 0x0
Scan:    0x2 0x38 0x3 0x4
Scan: In write_callback  status = 0x0
Scan: In image_callback
Scan:    Urb status = 0xffffffb9 Urb length = 0x0
Scan: In image_callback_fun - lost connection to scanner.
Scan: urb set to re-submit
Scan: In command_callback
Scan:    Urb status = 0xffffffb9 Urb length =  0x0
Scan: In command_callback_fun - lost connection to scanner.
Scan: urb set to re-submit
usb 1-6: USB disconnect, address 11
BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 6b6b6b93
 printing eip:
c04bd310
*pde = 00000000
Oops: 0000 [#1]
SMP
last sysfs file: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-6/bConfigurationValue
Modules linked in: vfat fat pdi_ps3_drv_scanner(U) xt_limit xt_tcpudp xt_state         ip_conntrack nfnetlink iptable_filter ip_tables x_tables loop dm_mirror dm_multipath     scsi_dh video backlight sbs power_meter hwmon i2c_ec dell_wmi wmi button battery asus_acpi     ac lp joydev snd_hda_intel snd_seq_dummy sg snd_seq_oss snd_seq_midi_event snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_pcm_oss snd_mixer_oss snd_pcm snd_timer parport_pc snd_page_alloc snd_hwdep snd parport tpm_tis tpm soundcore r8169 tpm_bios i2c_i801 serio_raw pcspkr pl2303 usbserial mii i2c_core dm_raid45 dm_message dm_region_hash dm_log dm_mod dm_mem_cache usb_storage ata_piix libata sd_mod scsi_mod ext3 jbd uhci_hcd ohci_hcd ehci_hcd
CPU:    3
EIP:    0060:[<c04bd310>]    Tainted: G     --------------------    VLI
EFLAGS: 00010202   (2.6.18-371.6.1.el5debug #1)
EIP is at sysfs_hash_and_remove+0x18/0x103
eax: 6b6b6b6b   ebx: f4be5bf4   ecx: c0570543   edx: 6b6b6b6b
esi: f4be5b0c   edi: f3cd936c   ebp: f3cd93c4   esp: f7fb2ee0
ds: 007b   es: 007b   ss: 0068
Process khubd (pid: 126, ti=f7fb2000 task=ca2fc5b0 task.ti=f7fb2000)
Stack: f4be5c50 6b6b6b6b f764d16c f4be5bf4 f4be5b0c f3cd936c f3cd93c4 c0570557
       f4be5b0c f3cd93a0 f3cd936c f7c8da2c c057066e f7fb2f28 c05a3db1 f7fb2f28
       c06827a6 00000000 305f7065 c06d0030 f3cd936c f3cd93c4 c05a39db f3cd96cc
Call Trace:
 [<c0570557>] device_del+0x5c/0x16b
 [<c057066e>] device_unregister+0x8/0x10
 [<c05a3db1>] usb_remove_ep_files+0x53/0x75
 [<c05a39db>] usb_remove_sysfs_dev_files+0xf/0x6c
 [<c059db5e>] usb_disconnect+0xa7/0xe0
 [<c059e668>] hub_thread+0x327/0x987
 [<c0439ed9>] kthread+0xa1/0xec
 [<c0439fab>] autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x2d
 [<c059e341>] hub_thread+0x0/0x987
 [<c0439ef8>] kthread+0xc0/0xec
 [<c0439e38>] kthread+0x0/0xec
 [<c0405e0f>] kernel_thread_helper+0x7/0x10
 =======================
Code: 8b 40 24 8b 40 40 c3 8b 40 14 8b 00 c3 8b 40 14 8b 00 c3 55 57 56 53 83 ec 0c 85 c0 89 44 24 04 89 14 24 0f 84 e5 00 00 00 89 c2 <8b> 40 28 85 c0 0f 84 d8 00 00 00 8b 52 70 05 90 00 00 00 89 54
EIP: [<c04bd310>] sysfs_hash_and_remove+0x18/0x103 SS:ESP 0068:f7fb2ee0
```

Comment: Oops: 0000 means no page was found.  The fault was in kernel mode while handling an interrupt.  There are several functions on the stack, but the crash was in hiddev_report_event() somewhere -- likely handling a link list that has a bogus member.  That's my take from looking at what is posted.

Comment: Thank you Peter.  As you probably have seen we have a tainted kernel with the 3rd party driver.  The crash occurs right when we try to read a scan, so do you think it's an issue with the 3rd party driver or are we exposing something in the kernel USB driver? I know these are vague questions.  If you can give me a little direction to dig deeper I would be very thankful. - Regards, Antonio

Comment: I wouldn't be too focused on the 'tainted' driver.  That means, among other things, that it may not be open source built into a stock kernel.  Many/most tainted drivers are functionally sound.  Several other things can taint a kernel.  My guess is that this fault is due to mismanagement of memory buffers.

Comment: Hello Peter L.  If you're out there.  Can you take a look at the edited information in my original question?  I have since updated to the latest CentOS 5.5 released kernel (2.6.18-371.6.1), but still got a kernel panic. However this time the panic occured on the command "khubd" and not on "swapper". I was able to capture the dump and have provided what I hope is relevant information to pinpoint this problem. Is it a bug in the kernel or something in the driver? Thanks, Antonio

Comment: khubd is the USB hub daemon.  It is likely not the source of the crash, which is likely a buggy USB driver.  BTW, 'swapper' is a process that is always running and often shows up in crash dumps as current, but is almost never at fault either.  It looks like the the device may have been disconnected at the time of the crash.  Not enough info to know exactly what happened, but the crash is around sysfs_hash_and_remove().  Usually the faulty call would be several calls above this or in a different context.  BTW, that kernel may be new for that version of CentOS, but it is very old.

Comment: @PeterL. Thanks for all your help.  We've haven't had much success in figuring out these crash.  I did move up to a later kernel (3.4.13), but not the latest because of an issue with a driver.  However I am going to push again and see if we can get a much new kernel working.  In the meantime under the 3.4.13 kernel we get consistent hangs and stack traces that are outputted to the screen.  With the older kernel and debug off, the machine would just go blank.  In the next comment I've have attached three images of the crashed machines.  Can you tell if this is pointing to some faulty HW?

Comment: Screenshots from the crashes. (sorry about formatting in the comments, but the links still work)  All look very similar.  (screen 1)http://s26.postimg.org/ofrdubyl5/Kernel_Hang2014_07_08.jpg           
(Screen 2)http://s26.postimg.org/r9z4liq55/Kernel_Hang2014_07_04.jpg                                                (Screen 3) http://s26.postimg.org/czu5nrz6h/Kernel_Hang2014_08_10.jpg

Comment: Without the source code it will be difficult to debug this further.  It looks like a call into enqueue_entity() and something occuring during an interrrupt is causing this panic.

Comment: Hello @PeterL., can you contact me via email, it is on my profile.  I'm also in San Diego.  Thanks,  Antonio

Comment: I guess email address info in profiles is marked private, so I can't see yours.  You can contact me at spinlocknull <at> yahoo.com.  Please mention in the subject line [stackoverflow].

Comment: This whole problem is looking like a bad memory module or at least the combination of HW and the particular ICs on this memory module. When putting in the "same" brand/product number memory with different ICs, we do not get these crashes. It's interesting that the same brand/product number of memory can have different ICs between two modules. The latest kernel we are running is 3.4.13, we have loaded 3.10 and 3.15 kernels but have not done enough testing to see if these newer kernels can prevent the crash with the suspect memory modules.

Comment: In the past I've seen component manufacturers brand a particular product identically but have different sub-components.  From what you have described, I think you are right that this is a hardware issue.

Comment: Just wanted to give a quick update.  We did have some bad memory, however that was not the main culprit.  It looks like a kernel bug in the USB area.  We are upgrading the kernel to a 3.X version and I will report back if that solves the issue.